# RSACryptoServiceProvider Public/Private Keys Import

Tags: c#, .net, rsa, public-key-encryption, private-key

I want to Sign and Verify Data via **RSACryptoServiceProvider**

For this, I need Public and Private keys.

In my project, I store MyPublic and Private keys in XML files.

One time, I generate MyPublic and Private Keys

```
public bool SignutureCheckForVerify(string myData, byte[] SignedData)
    {
        ...

        RSACryptoServiceProvider RSAalg = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
             RSAalg.FromXmlString(MyPublicKey());
        return RSAalg.VerifyData(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(myData), new   MineCryptoService(), SignedData);

       ...

    }

    private static string MyPublicKey()
    {
        return "<RSAKeyValue><Modulus>-----Pubic Key Here ----</RSAKeyValue>";
    }
```

At the Above, I showed that "Verify Data Via Public Keys"

My SignData method is similar.

At there,

```
  RSAalg.FromXmlString(GetPrivateKey());
   ...
  RSAalg.SignData(...)
```

My question si that; At some example, I recognized that; Public and Private keys import via crt/pem/cert etc. certificate files. On there I stored on XML files.

İs My solution wrong?

The second question that,

If I use this method to import keys

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tswxhw92(v=vs.110).aspx

GetKeyFromContainer("MyKeyContainer");

IS MyKeyContainer private and public keys  static?

At each run, Can I have same **private key/public key**

or each running I have different key set?*emphasized text*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is My solution wrong?

That depends on your requirements and threat model. The signature generation of `RSACryptoServiceProvider` should be explicitly set to a hash other than MD5 or SHA-1. It's not clear from your question if this has taken place.

> If I use this method to import keys
>
> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tswxhw92(v=vs.110).aspx
>
> `GetKeyFromContainer("MyKeyContainer");`
>
> Is MyKeyContainer private and public keys static?

Yes, that's the general idea of using a key store anyway.

> At each run, Can I have same private key/public key? Or should I have different key set each time I generate a signature?

Yes you can, given that you use an ample key size, say 2048 bit or higher.

---

Actually, for your solution to be secure the receiver needs to *trust* the public key. When no trust is established, anybody could send you their public key instead.

Comment: Thaks a lot for your answer, What about store in XML file to store keys. And what is the differences about Storege in XML vs. Storege in Certificate file. Can you help me?

Comment: XML is used for proprietary storage of Microsoft. Storing a public key in a certificate allows you  to store additional data within the certificate. Certificates can be "self signed" with the private key or signed by a certificate authority (or, in case of PGP, "anybody") which allows you to create a PKI. Note that the subject "key management" is huge. It goes beyond StackOverflow to discuss all the options and the implications of specific choices.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes RSACryptoServiceProvider requires the algorithm as an argument, what do you mean it defaults to SHA-1?  (It only supports SHA-1 for OAEP, but that's encryption, not signing.).

Comment: @bartonjs Right. It's the property value returned by calling `SignatureAlgorithm`. But I got confused as the hash method argument is substituted by `new   MineCryptoService()` in the question above, whatever that is.